# Cython import function from other pyx

Tags: cython

Two `pyx` files,

`f1.pyx`

```python
cpdef double func1():
     return 0.01
```

`f2.pyx`

```python
from f1 cimport func1
```

How could I import `func1` from `f1.pyx`? The reason is that I have different sections and want to put them in separate `pyx` files. But I couldn't import after I break them up.

Answer (score 6):

When you `cimport` a function from another file Cython needs a definition file (a `*.pxd` file) as well as the implementation file. (see [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-c-functions) for the relevant section of the documentation)

If you also create a file called `f1.pxd` containing the following:

```python
cpdef double func1()
```

Your example should compile.